What happens when the feedback loop is also connected to the non inverting input in an op-amp
I am trying to understand this tone control circuit in a guitar pedal. The image was taken from https://www.electrosmash.com/tube-screamer-analysis:

I do not know how to think about that feedback loop, since it is also connected to the non inverting input of the op-amp. Could someone help me out in understanding how this circuit works and maybe link some literature i can read about that talks about this kind of topology?

I don't know of any literature on that particular circuit. But it's not hard to analyze. C5 is important. But not to block DC. It adds another order to the circuit. You have a loaded-down low-pass in R7 and C5, that is interacted with another order due to C6. What kind of talking about are you looking for? Can you read a transfer function well?

There is a tone control network at P2, C6, R8, allowing the user to adjust the treble content of the signal. By changing the position of P2, the user can vary the cutoff frequency of the high-pass filter, enhancing or reducing the higher frequencies.
The op-amp amplifies the input signal. The feedback loop at R11 and C7 provide frequency-dependent feedback to control the gain and tone shaping further. At higher frequencies, the feedback reduces the gain, which helps in maintaining a smoother and more controlled tone.
Volume control at P3 adjusts the overall output level, allowing the user to set the desired output signal strength. The second R11 near P3 just provides additional stability. R9 is providing a bias voltage. R7 and C5 provide a low filter for the input.

But why place a high pass filter that way? why not just place it after the low pass filter at the beggining, instead of connecting it to the feedback loop that i dont get what it does?

@JuanAldrey Colin is mistaken. C5 doesn't block DC signals. If Vin is left open, then the opamp output is 4.5 V. If Vin is grounded, then the opamp output is about 410 mV. So DC certainly isn't blocked.

How do C7 contribute to the feedback?

@periblepsis Thanks for catching that. I fixed my answer. I misread the schematic.

As @periblepsis pointed out ... C5 does not block DC signals.
Here is the behavior shown with microcap v12

Note that behavior changes at the limit of the potentiometer (near 0 and 1).
In the other positions, changes are very "tiny".
Here is the behavior with a 1 uF wired to generator.

With capacitors of 0.22 uF ... the behaviour should be "more" different.


and that R4, C2 and R6 act like a high pass filter? I still dont get why is it placed that way :(

Yes. They change a "little" the frequency of behavior. More the response amplitude.

@Juan Aldrey  --  Your capacitor C5 and C6 are really 0.22 F ?

it isn´t my circuit, im pretty sure it´s supposed to be uF. Maybe thats why the initial frequency response you added doesnt seem to show a HP filter?

@JuanAldrey Are you still needing help with this?

i think i understand how i have to analyze it, maybe i just apply superposition to the voltage after the initial low pass filter. analyze it as two generators, one in the inverting input, another in the non inverting input. I havent tried it, but i think that could work!
